# How to tap to zoom an image like in instagram? Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, imageview, pinchzoom

I am trying to get a similar functionality to Instagram, when you tap or
pinch on an image, and now the image covers the screen above all the
other views, [like
this](https://pub.dev/packages/zoom_pinch_overlay/versions/1.4.1+3/gen-res/gen/demo.webp)

I have a Fragment with 3 images within a Constraint Layout, and I use
a Navigation component.  These images should be zoomed in when someone
taps on them, like focusing on the image.

At first, I tried using other fragments to simulate this. My approach
was to use buttons, then when you tap the button, it navigates to
another fragment with the image on a bigger scale. However, due to the
things I'm doing with the fragment, this method does not work because
it resets the rest of the information when navigating through
fragments.

Then, I tried to use
[PhotoView](https://github.com/photoview/photoview), but due to the
need to make the layout responsive, it doesn't work, because the image
can only be zoomed within the constraints set like this:

```
  <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
                     android:id="@+id/img_contenido"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="0dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                     android:src="@drawable/a_img3_entidad"
                     app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/txt_contenido2"
                     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                     app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.06"
                     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_contenido" />
```

[The constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFlKQ.png)
[Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N0lf.png) [Zoomed
in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCzbO.png)

So that is useless to me because I need the images to take basically
over the screen.

I then tried [ZoomHelper](https://github.com/Aghajari/ZoomHelper), but
since I am using a fragment with a navigation Component, I have no clue
how to implement it properly.

I also came across this [zoom_pinch_overlay
package](https://pub.dev/packages/zoom_pinch_overlay) which does
precisely what I need, but I am a complete stranger to Flutter, and I
suppose I cannot use it in any way with my app

What is the best way to do it, or which approach should I try to
figure out?

Comment: Apologies for quoting the whole post. The site would not let me post it otherwise, it kept giving me the "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted" error every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what I need through [StfalconImageViewer](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/StfalconImageViewer)

Just in case anyone ever has a similar situation with ViewBinding and Fragments, to implement it with a single image to test, i did it this way:

```
//Set up StfalconImageViewer when the image is clicked
            binding.imgNota.setOnClickListener {
                showImageWithStfalconViewer()
            }
```

And the method:

```
private fun showImageWithStfalconViewer() {
        // Replace 'R.drawable.img' with the actual drawable resource ID or image URL
        val imageUrl = R.drawable.img
        val images = listOf(imageUrl)

        val builder = StfalconImageViewer.Builder<Int>(requireContext(), images) { view, image ->
            // Load the image directly into the ImageView
            view.setImageResource(image)
        }

        // Optional set a transparent background color
        builder.withBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
            .allowSwipeToDismiss(true) // Allow dismissing by clicking outside the image
            .show()
    }
```